# Trim() String After the word is done

Tags: android, trim

What I am trying to accomplish here is to trim the String after the word is finished. But also trying to stay efficient, and not use `StringArray.length` since some String are longer than 2k characters.

```
int len = 140;
String str = Html.fromHtml((cureent.getTextContent().replaceAll("\n",""))).toString();
char[] StringArray;
StringArray = str.toCharArray();
for(int Index=140;Index < 150;Index++) {
    Log.d("Current Letter",String.valueOf(StringArray[Index]));
    if (String.valueOf(StringArray[Index]).equals(" ")){
        Log.d("Found E at" + String.valueOf(Index) ,"The Value is " + String.valueOf(StringArray[Index]));
    }
    item.setDescription(Html.fromHtml(cureent.getTextContent()).toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim().substring(0,Index).replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim());
}
```

E in my log Stands for Empty space

here is a bit of what the log returns.

```
2018-05-17 17:46:47.492 2616-2653/com.apo.rssredaer D/Found E at148: The Value is  
2018-05-17 17:46:47.495 2616-2653/com.apo.rssredaer D/Found E at141: The Value is  
2018-05-17 17:46:47.498 2616-2653/com.apo.rssredaer D/Found E at145: The Value is
```

But I cant get it to trim right after the word. I still get words trimmed in the middle or whatever position they are trimmed at

Example. lets say I have this string that I got from My rss.

And so, in honor of the antechinus’ tragic death, we give you a small sampling of the for the example I'll use 14 instead of 140 as my counter, and I'll count from 0.
Trimming it will return to me:

"And so, in hon"

But whenever this is the case. I want it to keep going and trim it at

"And so, in honor"

hope I make some sense.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Trim after which word is finished?
You're getting that print out because the character is " ".

Comment: yes exactly . trim after the word ends near the 140th possition. its an rss feed article. so the word I will trim after. is the one that heppens to have latters in that possition . if it makes sence. if not I can make an example

Comment: @Demeteor :: You might want to look at the solution I provided. No need to run through a `for` loop and it takes care of the situation when your string does not have a " " character between the 140th and 150th character in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK try this:

```
int position = 0; //create a pointer
        for (int index = 140; index < 150; index++) {
            if (str.charAt(index).equals(" ")) {
                position = index;
                break; //stop the loop when you find a space

            }
        }

//create a substring from 0 to Index
 item.setDescription(Html.fromHtml(str.substring(0, position));
```

Comment: This worksI think but I have to do position = index -1;
do you think this will cause any problems ?
Edit 2: All the articles for now at least seem fine.

Comment: Should be fine. Just be careful that your string is never less than 140 characters or you'll get a null pointer exception. Also your HTML might get malformed if you cut off a bunch of characters at the end.

Comment: Also if it helps you, could you mark my answer as correct and upvote please :)

Comment: yes I will. one last question. in the case of the error you mentioned. if I did special check up exaple. if string.length <140. then just do the item.setdescription i will be ok?

Comment: Yeah but if your string is huge, that could be bad. In which case why don't you just trim it at 140 characters and add "..." to the end?

Comment: That can be the best option , I thought of it. but it looked ugly. thats the reason why I thought of triming after the word (they are in cardviews.)

Comment: In a textview you can also use `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:maxLines="4 (or whatever)"` if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do this:

```
private String truncateTextMaxLength(String text, int maxLength){
    String result = text;
    int len = text.length();
    if(len < maxLength){
        return result;
    }

    int i = text.lastIndexOf(0, maxLength);
    result = text.substring(0, i);

    return result;
}
```

Now you can call just like this:

```
String s = truncateTextMaxLength(myText, 150);
```

. 
Note that with the other code there could be the possibility that there is no " " between the 140th and 150th character.